# Negative values converted as Positives in Seperate_rows function

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi I am trying to split vaues (From single Vale) in to multiple rows

My Data frame is as follows.

```
col_1=c("a","b")
col_2 = c("-1,-3,null","44,-77,null")
df = data.frame(col_1,col_2)

out_df= tidyr::separate_rows(df, col_2,convert = T)
```

In the above statement values which are negative are converted into positive values.The expected output is as follows.

```
col_1     col_2

a          -1
a          -3
a           null
b           44
b           -77
b           null
```

Is there any changes required in seperate_rows function..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the change required is you need to explicitly mention the `sep` argument since by default it takes any non-alphanumeric character as separator which also includes minus sign (`-`) .

```
out_df = tidyr::separate_rows(df, col_2, sep = ',', convert = TRUE)
```

You can turn `'null'` to `NA` and then convert `col_2` to numeric.

```
library(dplyr)

out_df %>% mutate(col_2 = as.numeric(na_if(col_2, 'null')))

#  col_1 col_2
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 a        -1
#2 a        -3
#3 a        NA
#4 b        44
#5 b       -77
#6 b        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R method:

```
> col_1 <- sub('(^[ab]).*','\\1',paste0(rep(df$col_1, each = length(unlist(strsplit(df$col_2, split = ',')))/2),unlist(strsplit(df$col_2, split = ','))))
> col_2 <- sub('(^[ab])(.*)','\\2',paste0(rep(df$col_1, each = length(unlist(strsplit(df$col_2, split = ',')))/2),unlist(strsplit(df$col_2, split = ','))))
> df <- data.frame(col_1, col_2)
> df
  col_1 col_2
1     a    -1
2     a    -3
3     a  null
4     b    44
5     b   -77
6     b  null
```